# How to activate login only when app is quit?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, localauthentication

I have a login system in my app. The code is like this:

```
func showLoginView() {
    if !isAuthenticated {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginView", sender: self)
    }
}

@objc func appWillResignActive(_ notification : Notification) {
    view.alpha = 0
    isAuthenticated = true
    showLoginView()
    didReturnFromBackground = true

}

@objc func appDidBecomeActive(_ notification : Notification) {
    if didReturnFromBackground{
    showLoginView()
    }
}
```

Essentially this prompts the loginView whenever I exit the app. But I only want it to do so if I quit the app. i.e., double tap on the home button and remove the app from memory. If I just press the home button, and the app dismisses, when I open the app again, it shouldn't ask me for a login. How will I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `appDidBecomeActive` is called every time we come back from being deactivated.

Move the functionality into `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`. That is called if the app is terminated and relaunched, but *not* if the app is merely deactivated or backgrounded and brought back to the front.

Comment: Could you please give me an exact syntax for the use?

Comment: No, not all the code, just how to evoke the function. If you can't then it's fine.

Comment: This question has been answered many times here. I even have a downloadable example: https://github.com/mattneub/RegistrationExample/blob/master/RegistrationExample/AppDelegate.swift